# Referencing last cell value in column

Tags: macos, apple-numbers

I need a formula for a cell in table A to reference the last cell value in a table B column C. The table B column currently has lots of blank cells that will have data added to it periodically, and the cell in table A will need to keep updating automatically.

I’ve tried INDEX((C,COUNT(C)), which I saw on an Excel forum, but this didn’t have the desired effect on on my Numbers spreadsheet.